# Problem - any hidden field in Update Panel does not get updated

Tags: asp.net

I am using C# for my programming.

I am facing issue, that my hidden variable value is not being updated when it is in update panel. Please see below code for aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidCurrentDate" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidTripIds" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidTripDetails" value="" />

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="uprogTrips" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <span style="display: block; text-align: center">
                    <p style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: larger; font-weight: bold;">
                        <img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Processing..." /><br />
                        <br />
                        Processing...</p>
                </span>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTripsGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvAllTrips" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvAllTrips_RowDataBound"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="gvAllTrips_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="35" Position="TopAndBottom" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />                    
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddSortBy" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddFilterBy" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cbPageOptions" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and below is the code where I am trying to update one of the hidden field with my CS code.

Interesting, when I am trying to debug its showing all the values, however when I see it f on page source it doesn't give any value.

Here is my aspx.cs code:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtTrips = null;
    WEX.Prototype.Data.TripDA tripDA = new WEX.Prototype.Data.TripDA();
    string tID = hidTripIds.Value;
    string[] tripIDs = new string[1000];
    tripIDs = tID.Split(',');


    foreach (string tripID in tripIDs)
    {
        TripSummaryBO tripSummaryBO = tripDA.getTripSummary(Convert.ToInt32(tripID));
        if (tripSummaryBO.tripLastEditedOnDate > Convert.ToDateTime(hidCurrentDate.Value))
        {

            WEX.Prototype.Service.WSProxies WSProxies = new WEX.Prototype.Service.WSProxies();
            dtTrips = WSProxies.Build();
            Session["AllTrips"] = dtTrips;
            dtTrips = (DataTable)Session["AllTrips"];
            if (dtTrips != null)
            {
                if (cnt==0)
                {
                    hidTripDetails.Value = ("Trip name-" + tripSummaryBO.tripName + " was modified by user " + tripSummaryBO.tripLastEditedBy);
                }
                else
                {
                    hidTripDetails.Value = hidTripDetails.Value + " <br/> " + ("Trip name-" + tripSummaryBO.tripName + " was modified by user " + tripSummaryBO.tripLastEditedBy);
                }
                BuildGridViewControl(dtTrips);
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //upTripsGrid.Triggers.Clear();
            PageInit();
        }            
    }
}
```

Please suggest

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your hidden input fields are not within the update panel control. Any asynchronous round trips to the server will cause only those controls within the `UpdatePanel` itself to update on the UI, so even though the code-behind runs and updates the hidden fields, on the front end they stay the same because they sit outside the panel.

Try moving the hidden fields within the `<ContentTemplate>` tag:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTripsGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidCurrentDate" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidTripIds" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidTripDetails" value="" />
        ....
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: good stuff. note that if you want to add the hiddenField dynamically you need the ContentTemplateContainer : updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(hiddenFieldX);     and to find it later use: panel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.OfType<HiddenField>().First();