# Get anchor height and width in code behind when they are not specified in the code?

Tags: asp.net, html, anchor

I have an anchor set to display:inline-block and it wraps around Text tight like I want to,without height or width specified.  Now I need to get this width and height from my  code-behind.

Can someone explain to me how can I get these values, even though they are not specified and merely inherited from the width/height of the text inside?

**UPDATE: Found Solution**

This can be done using JavaScript property offsetHeight and offsetWidth of element.This is code I put together in haste:

JS:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function GetAnchorSize() {
        var buttonWidth = document.getElementById('<%= button.ClientID %>').offsetWidth;
        var buttonHeight = document.getElementById('<%= button.ClientID %>').offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById('<%= buttonWidth.ClientID %>').value = buttonWidth;
        document.getElementById('<%= buttonHeight.ClientID %>').value = buttonHeight;
    }
 </script>
```

Element which size I need and two hidden fields to enter value:

```
<input type="hidden" id="buttonWidth" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="buttonHeight" runat="server" />

<a id="button" href="#"  onmousemove="GetAnchorSize();"  runat="server" 
                    style="display: inline-block; border-color: Black;
                    text-decoration: none; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; background-repeat:no-repeat;">Text</a>
```

I set it up so it gets updated on mouse move you can set it up on which ever event you need to get values updated.

And to get values in codebehind:

```
int btnWidth = Convert.ToInt32(buttonWidth.Value);
int btnHeight= Convert.ToInt32(buttonHeight.Value);
```

Comment: I'd retag this as a JavaScript question. The height and width aren't finalized until the page is rendered by the browser.

Comment: The anchor is in Update Panel so it gets renderd partialy accrding to user settings.

Comment: If you're not explicitly forcing a size, the pixel dimensions are not determined until the control is rendered on the client. You can't get that information from the server unless you retrieve it from the DOM via JavaScript and send it back to the server.

Comment: @DavidLively Thanks for info. As I posted below would I get correct value using Js offsetHeight/width like I mentioned in answer below?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll want to add "runat=server" to the element in question. Also, don't forget to assign an ID to it. After that you should be able to access it in C#.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, no Im asking how to get height and width of element(div,a) when height and width are not specified in Style tag or css and element is streched with controls inside.

Comment: Oh I see. You could use something like this: element.Style.Add("width", "300px");

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try dealing with presentation concerns only on the client side, but if you really need to retrieve those values, I think you should use a hidden field, and get its value on PostBack.

Make sure that your element (A, DIV, etc.) is visible, else you may get wrong values.

Put the values inside a hidden field :

```
<input type="hidden" id="elSize" runat="server" />
```

Then retrieve the value in your code-behind :

```
elSize.Value
```

If you use jQuery, it's easy to retrive the size : use width() and height() (or outerWidth and outerHeight if you want margin/border/padding).

Using plain JavaScript, you should be able to use ClientWidth and ClientHeight I think.

EDIT : put your hidden fields inside the ContentTemplate tag.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTripsGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidCurrentDate" value="" />
```

Source : [Problem - any hidden field in Update Panel does not get updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221460/problem-any-hidden-field-in-update-panel-does-not-get-updated)

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for pure ASP.NET, since I don't know anything about jQuery, I'm thinking that maybe Js offsetHeight/Width might work is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, it depends if you want only the width or also the margin/padding/border. And you didn't say it was an UpdatePanel, you must be careful to put your field inside the ContentTemplate tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that since this element wraps tight around the Text, it's size depends on the size of the text... and the size of the text depends on the size and scaling of browser window.  Therefore, the size of your element depends on the size of the browser window, and you can't know how large this item will be before it is rendered by the browser.

The best solution here is to implement whatever you are trying to do in javascript, which can easily ask the browser DOM how large is the element.

If this is simply not an option the next best thing you can hope for is to record this server-side after your first post back (and watch it on each post back because this will change if the user re-sizes their browser window).