# Unable to get hiddenfield value via jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to set the value of a hiddenfield via c# code, then get the value of that hiddenfield from jquery.  I'm able to set it correctly in c#, however when I try to get it in jquery, the value's blank.  Here's my code.  My c# code executes first, followed by my jquery code:

**c#**

```
if (IsPostBack)
  {
      //set the value of the hidden field
      hdnPostbackControlId.Value = "Hello World!;          
 }
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var controlId = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnPostbackControlId').val();
 });
```

In the above jquery code, "controlId" comes back blank.  Any idea how to fix this & get my hiddenfield value to pass to jquery correctly?

Comment: Does your hidden field renders correctly in your HTML?

Comment: What does `console.log($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnPostbackControlId'))` show you?

Comment: check to make sure your document.ready function is firing after your postback

Comment: also change your selector to have this: `$('<%= hdnPostbackControlId.ClientID %>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221460/problem-any-hidden-field-in-update-panel-does-not-get-updated/22020685#22020685):

I failed to mention in my original post, that I'm using an updatepanel on this page. My hiddenfield was placed outside of the updatepanel. This caused the hiddenfield to be blank.

I moved the hiddenfield inside the updatepanel, and it now works fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend letting ASP.NET generate the ID for you:

```
var controlId = $('#<%= hdnPostBackControlID.ClientID %>').val();
```

That will ensure you always have the correct ID, which may have changed because of the rendered control tree, and may be a reason you aren't finding it.  This trick worked great for me, I'm surprised you aren't seeing it in subsequent postbacks...